# How to move tabs in guake

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts, guake

How to move the tabs in guake,

e.g. tab1 tab2 --> tab2 tab1

Searched and found this thread : https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/35

It says this issue and is fixed now, so anyone knows how to do it. !

Comment: "Page not found." Ah, you have 2 copies of the URL next to each other.

Answer (score 7):

Keyboard shortcut on Mint Cinnamon 19: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>pgup</kbd>/<kbd>pgdown</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't mentioned the version of Ubuntu you are using, but the latest version for Ubuntu is [0.4.4](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/guake), whereas this feature was added in 0.5.1.

The command to view the version you are using is:
`guake -a` (or `guake --about`)

If you don't have the latest version in your distribution repo, you will have to compile from source, or use an alternative, like Terminator, XFCE4 Terminal, Yakuake, etc.

Comment: Yes ...I missed it...I don't have 0.5.1 version...